# For every row with data I need a row for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have timesheet data that I need to create a report for by date range. I need to have a row for each person for each day, and each time type. If there's no entry for that time type on a given day, i want null data. I've tried a left join, but it doesn't seem to be working. A cross join will give erroneous data.

The tables I have are a `Person` table (`personID, Name`), a `TimeLog` table (`TimeLogID, StartDate, EndDate, TimeLogTypeID`), and a `TimeLogType` table (`TimeLogTypeID, PersonID, Description, DeletedInd`)

All I can get in the result set is the rows with data, and not the empty rows for each `TimeLogType`

Here's what I have so far:

```
DECLARE 
    @startDate  DATE,
    @endDate    DATE

SET @startDate = '2014-05-01'
SET @endDate =   '2014-05-30'

SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, TimeLog.StartDateTime, 101) AS TimeLogDay,
    SUM(dbo.fnCalculateHoursAsDecimal(TimeLog.StartDateTime, TimeLog.EndDateTime)) AS Hours,
    TimeLog.PersonID,
    TimeLog.TimeLogTypeID

INTO #HourTable

FROM
    TimeLog

WHERE   
    TimeLog.StartDateTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate

GROUP BY
    CONVERT(DATE, TimeLog.StartDateTime, 101),
    TimeLog.TimeLogTypeID,  
    TimeLog.PersonID

SELECT 
    TimeLogType.Description,    
    #HourTable.*
FROM 
    TimeLogType LEFT JOIN
    #HourTable ON TimeLogType.TimeLogTypeID = #HourTable.TimeLogTypeID

WHERE 
    ISNULL(TimeLogType.DeletedInd, 0) = 0

ORDER BY
    PersonID, TimeLogDay, TimeLogType.TimeLogTypeID
```

The data goes something like this:

TimeLogType:
1, Billable
2, Non-Billable

Person:
1, Billy
2, Tom

TimeLog:
1, 1, 2014-05-01 08:00:00, 2014-05-01 09:00:00, 1, 0
2, 1, 2014-05-01 09:00:00, 2014-05-01 10:00:00, 1, 0
3, 2, 2014-05-01 08:00:00, 2014-05-01 08:30:00, 2, 0
4, 2, 2014-05-01 08:30:00, 2014-05-01 09:00:00, 1, 0
5, 1, 2014-05-02 08:00:00, 2014-05-02 09:00:00, 2, 0

Expected Output: (order by person, date, timelog type)
Day,        Person, Bill Type, Total Hours
2014-05-01, Billy,  Billiable,         2.0
2014-05-01, Billy,  Non-Billiable,    NULL
2014-05-02, Billy,  Billiable,         1.0
2014-05-02, Billy,  Non-Billiable,    NULL
etc...
2014-05-01, Tom,    Billiable,         0.5
2014-05-01, Tom,    Non-Billiable,     0.5
etc...

Comment: can you give the sample data from the tables?

Comment: and a short, but descriptive example of the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Gordon's answer here's what I've come up with. I created it in steps so I could see what was going on. I created the dates w/o the master..spt_values table. I also created a temp table of people so I could select just the ones that had a TimeLogRecord, and then re-use it to pull in details for the final select. Let me know if there's any way to make this run faster.

```
DECLARE 
    @startDate  DATE,
    @endDate    DATE

SET @startDate = '2014-01-01'
SET @endDate =   '2014-01-31'

-- create day rows --
;WITH dates(TimeLogDay) AS 
(
    SELECT @startDate AS TimeLogDay
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, TimeLogDay)
    FROM dates 
    WHERE TimeLogDay < @enddate
)

-- create a type row for each day --
SELECT
    dates.TimeLogDay,
    tlt.TimeLogTypeID

INTO #TypeDate

FROM 
    dates CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT
        TimeLogType.TimeLogTypeID
     FROM 
        TimeLogType 
     WHERE 
        ISNULL(TimeLogType.DeletedInd, 0) = 0
    ) AS TLT 

-- create a temp person table for referance later ---
SELECT * INTO #person FROM Person WHERE Person.personID IN 
        (SELECT Timelog.PersonID FROM TimeLog WHERE TimeLog.StartDateTime BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)

-- sum up the log times and tie in the date/type rows --
SELECT  
    #TypeDate.TimeLogDay,
    #TypeDate.TimeLogTypeID,
    #person.PersonID,
    SUM(dbo.fnCalculateHoursAsDecimal(TimeLog.StartDateTime, TimeLog.EndDateTime)) AS Hours

INTO #Hours

FROM
    #person CROSS JOIN
    #TypeDate LEFT JOIN
    TimeLog ON
        TimeLog.PersonID = #person.PersonID AND
        TimeLog.TimeLogTypeID = #TypeDate.TimeLogTypeID AND
        #TypeDate.TimeLogDay = CONVERT(DATE, TimeLog.StartDateTime, 101)

GROUP BY
    #TypeDate.TimeLogDay,
    #TypeDate.TimeLogTypeID,
    #person.PersonID

-- now tie in the details to complete --
SELECT
    #Hours.TimeLogDay,
    TimeLogType.Description,
    Person.LastName,
    Person.FirstName,
    #Hours.Hours

FROM
    #Hours LEFT JOIN
    Person ON #Hours.PersonID = Person.PersonID LEFT JOIN
    TimeLogType ON #Hours.TimeLogTypeID = TimeLogType.TimeLogTypeID

ORDER BY
    Person.FirstName,
    Person.LastName,
    #Hours.TimeLogDay,
    TimeLogType.SortOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate all the combinations first and then use `left join` to bring in the information you want.  I think the query is like this:

```
with dates as (
      select dateadd(day, number - 1, mind) as thedate
      from (select min(StartDate) as mind, max(EndDate) as endd
            from TimeLogType
           ) tlt join
           master..spt_values v
           on dateadd(day, v.number, mind) <= tlt.endd
     )
select p.PersonId, tlt.TimeLogTypeId, d.thedate, 
from Person p cross join
     (select tlt.* from TimeLogType tlt where ISNULL(TimeLogType.DeletedInd, 0) = 0
     ) tlt cross join
     date d left join
     TimeLog tl
     on tl.Person_id = p.PersonId and tl.TimeLogTypeId = tlt.TimeLogTypeId and
        d.thedate >= tl.StartDate and d.thedate <= tl.EndDate
```

Comment: I'm getting a few syntax errors with the CTE.  I had to put "master.." in front of the spt_values table, changed the alias from 'v' to 'dte' on the subselect before the join, but the line "select dateadd(day, number - 1, min(date)) as thedate" is giving me an error on the "min(date)" part

Comment: @user3033282 . . . Sorry about that.  Try it now.